# GWT onFocus event not getting triggered on text box

Tags: gwt, textbox, onfocus

onFocus event is not getting triggered on the text box. I have below code, i am using GWT 2.6.0

When i used the focus handler on text box then its working properly but i also have on browser event where i am not able to trigger focus event.Below is the code for on browser.

```
@Override
    public void onBrowserEvent( Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event,
            ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater )
    {
        String eventType = event.getType();     

      if( BrowserEvents.FOCUS.equals( eventType ) )
        {
           //Do what you want on focus
        }
```

Comment: What sort of text box is it? HTML's `<input>` or GWT's `TextBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the methods provided (for your ease) by GWT:

```java
textBox.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        //Do some operation onFocus event
    }
});
```

It's part of the `HasFocusHandlers` which is implemented by quite a few of GWT's widgets. Similar handlers can be found for mouse, keyboard, blur, etc. events.

For completeness sake: if you need to listen directly on the DOM `ONFOCUS` event on any `Widget`, you need to call the `sinkEvents` method first with the appropriate bits/flags (or override it in your widget). You can find the relevant flags in the [`Event`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html) class.

Comment: See i am using same code for the Integer box and its working properly there. Issue is only with textbox.

Comment: See i am using same code for the Integer box(Extended from ValueBox of GWT by passing <Integer>) and its working properly there. Issue is only with textBox.

Comment: Please share some more code - how do you instantiate your TextBox, how do you listen for the focus events, etc. Have you tried a FocusHandler or are you overwriting `onBrowserEvent`?

Comment: I am overwriting onBrowserEvent.

Comment: I have two place where i want to trigger this onFocus event. On adding focus handler on text box as given by you its working fine, but at other place i am overriding browser event and there its not triggerring event. I have update code in the question.

Comment: Have you called `sinkEvents(Event.ONFOCUS)` on this widget? The code you posted is hardly helpful - we can't see how you initialized the widget.